# Make PhpStorm change it's opinion about return value of framework function

Tags: php, laravel, ide, phpstorm

I use PhpStorm. Given a framework function or method, for example, `auth()->user()`, I need to change PhpStorm's opinion about it's return value's type.

In my case, this function is a part of Laravel framework and it returns an instance implementing `Authenticatable` interface. I have a `User` class which implements this interface and in **all** cases `auth()->user()` returns `User` instance.

`User` contains some methods and properties I'd surely like to see autocompleted by PhpStorm when I type `auth()->user()`, but it's not autocompleted since PhpStorm is only sure about `Authenticatable` nature of it's return value.

Changing framework's source code in `vendor/` is not acceptable since any patch would rewrite it, and I'd have to do it on every machine.

I've found out one could create a PhpStorm extension, but it's excessive, I guess. I could create some kind of IDE helper file, but I don't know how and don't know if it's the correct decision.

What is the best/correct/appropriate solution for this problem? Am I missing something?

Comment: *"Am I missing something?"* Well ... 2 moments: 1) In PhpStorm you cannot override some internal method with new signature (I'm referring to PHPDoc). 2) What you going to do with `auth('someAnotherGuard')->user()` kind of code .. where it will not be `User` .. but `AdminUser` for example (e.g. in case if you wish to have completely separate DB table for user of your Control Panel). Therefore intermediate variable is the most safest way here. See the answer below.

Comment: @LazyOne as soon as I get more guards I will leave it, but now I need it so much with only one guard. Anyway, `auth()->user()` is only an example, I'd be glad to understand how can I do that trick with any function. I've heard about ide-helper files which PHPStorm would scan and take some notes about the structure of the project, like ide-helper for laravel, but I don't know how to use this to change return value's type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assert type of the returned value, PHPStorm will be happy:

```
$user = auth()->user();
if ($user instanceof User) {
    // starting from this point PHPStorm should hint User's methods for $user.
}
```

Comment: If he uses intermediate variable (`$user` in our case) then for PhpStorm it will be enough to just add `/** @var MyUserClass $user */` before or after such line. From general (PHP) point of view using `instanceof` is a safer way -- that's for sure.

Comment: Yeah, it surely will, but it's kinda hard to do it all across the project (and it lacks logic since I always keep it User)

Comment: I just need a way to ALWAYS make PhpStorm SURE auth()->user() returns User, whatever it seems

Comment: @Alagunto You may try creating another class (same name/namespace) where you will re-declare all the methods with "correct" PHPDocs (you may place such file(s) anywhere in the project) ... but I'm not 100% sure that it will work -- at very least PhpStorm will be showing you "multiple classes exist" notice (not too visible though).

Comment: @LazyOne I've just tried it. PhpStorm doesn't show that return type is "correct" now (it just shows old type), but it highlights properties and methods of that new return type too (sic!), so it's kinda suitable for me. Thank you, mate!